# Convert array with double quotes in Snowflake

Tags: arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column with data like `"a, b, c"` coming in s3 in a csv file. I copied the file using copy into as an array into stage table which copies as `[   "a, b, c" ]`

Now,  I want to convert this into a column `["a","b","c"]`

I tried using try_cast and split functions but I did not get it to work properly as expected.

Basically I want the data coming in s3 as `"a, b, c"` to be an array column like `["a","b","c"]` finally in the final table.

Copy Command used:

```
copy into stage_table
     (domain, primary_iab_v1_0, related_iab_v1_0, urg1, urg2, urg3,  primary_iab_v2_2, related_iab_v2_2, file_name)
from (select t.$1 as domain
           , t.$2::array as primary_iab_v1_0
           , t.$3::array as related_iab_v1_0
           , t.$4 as urg1
           , t.$5 as urg2
           , t.$6 as urg3
           , t.$9::array as primary_iab_v2_2
           , t.$10::array as related_iab_v2_2
           , METADATA$FILENAME as file_name
        from @stage_location t)
on_error = skip_file force = true files = (:file_names)
file_format = (type = 'CSV' field_delimiter = ',' field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"' skip_header=1)
;
```

Comment: What cast & split functions have you already tried ? Do you need this to run directly within the COPY, or can it run as a separate CTAS operation to post process the table from the COPY?

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported transforms to use in Select within COPY is [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform#supported-functions). `SPLIT` is is in the list. I haven't tried it in COPY as you haven'd provided any sample data to test it.

But something like this should do it:

```
select ['a,b,c'] copy_array,  split(copy_array[0], ',') output_array ;
```

You need to select the delimited text string from the array using using `[0]`.

So if `primary_iab_v1_0` were the array you wanted to convert then:

```
split(t.$2:[0], ',') as primary_iab_v1_0
```

Answer (score 0):

so depending how you data actually looks there might be a clean-up step required:

```
select '"a, b, c"' as a
    ,'A, B, C' as b
    ,a::array as c
    ,to_array(b) as d
    ,split(a, ',') as e
    ,split(b, ',') as f
    ,trim(a, '"') as g
    ,split(g, ',') as h
```

so depending if your input string (which is Snowflake is only shown as single quotes). So if we want a string with a double quote, you can see the hoops jumping required to get `A` inputted.

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "a, b, c" | A, B, C | [ ""a, b, c"" ] | [ "A, B, C" ] | [ ""a", " b", " c"" ] | [ "A", " B", " C" ] | a, b, c | [ "a", " b", " c" ] |

so here, you can see to get the array of strings `H` from `A` then we need to strip the embedded double quotes, before splitting to avoid the extra quotes as seen in `E`.